# Recharts jest snapshot test: ResizeObserver with MUI Tabs

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui, react-testing-library, recharts

In our Project, we are running jest snapshot tests with React testing library. We are using both Recharts with ResponsiveContainer and MUI with Tabs in the project, and they are both rendered in a specific test.

When no polyfill for ResizeObserver is set, the test fails with

```
window.ResizeObserver is not a constructor
```

When setting the polyfill in the test setup:

```
global.ResizeObserver = require('resize-observer-polyfill');
```

the test is failing on the MUI Tabs with this:

```
    TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'children')
```

Is there a way to solve both problems with a elegant solution?